Target only top level headings jQuery
OK, I have some code that looks like this, and I want to target only the headings which are inside a container, but not inside another container inside of it (if that makes sense). Currently it catches them all. How do I change that? I know about the "not" selector, but I'm not sure how to tell jQuery "target headings inside haccordion, but not if they are inside something inside of that".
    <script>
    (document).ready(function(){
      $(".haccordion :header").css("background-color","yellow");
    });
    </script>
    
    <div class="haccordion">
    <h2>Target this</h2>
      <p class="section">Here is some text content</p>
    <h3>Target this</h3>
      <div class="section">
        <p>Here is some content with text and an image</p>
        <h3>Don't target this</h3>
        <p>Here is some more text</p>
      </div>
    <h3>Target this</h3>
      <section>
        <h4>Don't target this</h4>
        <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>


".haccordion > :header"

Easiest fix ever. Thanks!
